# Dynamically Creating and Removing Elements in javascript

Tags: javascript, removechild, appendchild

I was thinking im comfortable with adding and removing elements in js till two days ago when i ran into this trouble.

Ok , pls this is my problem:

I was trying to dynamically create divs, append to an elemnt on the page, add a handle to the new div i created in an array, then run a loop later and remove all the divs in the array (both from the array and the page)

This is my code for creating the divs:

```
var this_object=this;this.tempdivs=new Array();var thandle='';

var t=document.createElement('div');var br=document.createElement('br');
var txt=document.createTextNode(content_body);
t.appendChild(content);t.appendChild(txt);t.appendChild(br);
thandle=this_object.chat_rec_handle.appendChild(t);
this_object.tempdivs.push(thandle);
```

**this_object.chat_rec_handle** is where i append after creation, it actually gets appended.

My problem is when is want to remove the divs that i have created

```
    var divlength=this_object.tempdivs.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < divlength; i++)
    {
     var tempobj=this_object.tempdivs[this_object.tempdivs.length-1];
     alert(tempobj.parentNode); 
/* this alert gives me null, does that mean the parent no longer exists? */
     tempobj.parentNode.removeChild(tempobj);
     this_object.tempdivs.pop();
    }
```

This is very frustrating, but i know codes are not wrong, please what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Have you considered using JQuery? It makes these kinds of tasks much easier.

Comment: the person specifically requested for custom coding

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why not just use `i` as the index into the array of divs? The first line after the beginning of your for loop should be:

```
 var tempobj=this_object.tempdivs[i];
```

And then you can delete this line:

```
 this_object.tempdivs.pop();
```

Second, you may want to check to make sure the element has a parent (*i.e.* not already removed) before trying to remove it:

```
 tempobj.parentNode && tempobj.parentNode.removeChild(tempobj);
```

That change will prevent the error from occurring, but it will not fix its cause. You'll have to find out why. Without any other code posted, I cannot say anything else.

Comment: i think pop removes the last element from array, i didnt use 'i' cos im interested in the last element